# Difference between MySQL IS NOT NULL and != ''

Tags: sql, mysql, null, operators, conditional-statements

Is there any difference between MySQL

```
IF (myText IS NOT NULL) THEN
```

and

```
IF (myText != '') THEN
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there is a big difference between a [`NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) value and a blank/empty value.

Here's [one resource](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/null-vs-empty-zero-length-string/) that describes the differences.

When `myText IS NULL`:

- `myText IS NOT NULL` evaluates to `FALSE`
- `myText != ''` evaluates to `NULL` (which essentially behaves the same as `FALSE` would in this specific case you wrote)

However, you should not get into the habit of treating them the same, since most of the time they will behave differently: For example:

Assume you have a table `tbl`:

```
id   text
1    NULL
2    
3    abc
```

**Note:** 1 contains a `NULL` value, and 2 contains an empty string (`''`).

If you run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE text != ''
```

... it will return record 3.

If you run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE text IS NOT NULL
```

... it will return records 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a difference.

In simple words, **myText IS NOT NULL** specifies that myText is having **some value which could be '' too**.

Where as **myText != ''** specifies that it returns TRUE, if myText does NOT contain **an empty string**.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference. If the default value of a column is "NULL", then if no data has been set for a field, it is truly null. However, if the value of a field has been updated as '', it is not NULL, rather it is empty.

See here for more information [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)